# AWS ECS Cronjob - How to run my sh script in task?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-ecs

I want to make a cronjob on my AWS ECS.

I use AWS Scheduled task to run new task each 1 Hour.

But i need to run some sh script that in this task.

How it is work?

For example in crontab on my local PC I have this cron script:

```
0 * * * *     /home/scripts/cronjobs/test.sh
```

I want to have the same in AWS ECS.

Please can you help me

---

This does not work for me, or is this wrong place?
Screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqMOR.png

Comment: make sure your test.sh is executable and permission is okay.

Comment: Have you gone through this ??https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduled_tasks.html

Comment: Yes, but there is no information on how to run my test.sh script, just how to make a Scheduled task. Scheduled task - is not a problem. Problem ist how to run test.sh in Scheduled task.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a task definition for the AWS Scheduled Tasks. The docker image referenced in the task definition should run the command `/home/scripts/cronjobs/test.sh`.

Comment: Did you create a new task definition for the scheduled task?

Comment: I use the same task definition

Comment: That should work. But use `sh /home/scripts/cronjobs/test.sh`